# Need help with screen design

Tags: android

I need to create a new screen and I don’t know from where and how to start.

These are the requirements':

The screen will be separate in the middle while each side will hold few components (TextView) and will have different color. (two layouts or custom view ??)

The borders of the new screen should be rounded and padding.

Unfortunately I don’t have (yet) permission to upload an image for example so I hope my description was ok.

Can someone please give me few tips how to start this screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I belive this is something you should be able to google search, the basics of XML layout are quite simple and you can understand them easily through examples.

Most of the time, you can get what you want using nested LinearLayouts or using relative Layout, refrain from using absoluteLayout.

You can use [Droid Draw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) to get the basics going, but there comes a point where that tool just isnt powerful enough. Also, if you want an easy to read book that will get you started, [Beggining android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003VPWYCI) rocks.